# How to get values from model that contains a list in Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, model

i have a model that is for orders and also as a property, this one contains a list of products.

Order model contains (orderId, customerId, list products)
Products model contains (productid, description, amount)

So my question in this one is how can I get all customerId that contain in their order a specific product?

This one is implemented in Java Spring Boot with Hibernate

Thank you

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Type(type="uuid-char")
@Column(name = "order_id")
private UUID orderId;

@Type(type="uuid-char")
@Column(name = "customer_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
private UUID customerId;

@Column(name = "additional_info")
private String additionalInfo;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
})
@JoinTable(
        name = "orders_products",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
        }
)
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<> ();
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Type(type="uuid-char")
@Column(name = "product_id")
private UUID productId;

@Column(name = "label")
private String label;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "price")
private double price;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Order> orders= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Could you describe your models more precisely? Are the models JPA entities? Maybe you could add the code of both models :).

Comment: Check my question i've already updated with models.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the models with getters and setters and the like looks a little bit like this:

```
class Order {
  int orderId;
  int customerId;
  List<Product> products;
}

class Product {
  int productId;
  String description;
  int amount;
}
```

and you have a list of orders, you could use the Streaming API to achieve your goals:

```
Product wantedSpecificProduct = ..
List<Integer> targetedCustomerId = orders.stream()
  .filter(order -> order.getProducts().contains(wantedSpecificProduct))
  .map(Order::getCustomerId)
  .toList(); // `.collect(Collectors.toList())` pre Java 16
```